# Keras model with multiple outputs not converging

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am enjoying the simplicity that Keras offers, however I have not been successful in configuring a Keras regression model with multiple outputs.

More specifically, I have a Keras model that consumes X values with 308 columns and with 28 target Y values.  The model is (I think) quite simple and I would have thought it would converge quite quickly, but in fact is does not.

I am guessing here, but I think I have setup the model incorrectly and am looking for assistance on how to configure a Keras model to work properly.

Data information:

```
Number of rows: 46038
My input shape:  X_train: (46038, 308)
My target shape: Y_train: (46038, 28)
```

The inputs (X) are a series of floats representing values that influence the allocation of a resource.  The targets are a series of floats (which total/sum to 1.0 representing the actual percent allocation to a particular resource).  My goal is to predict resource pct allocations (Y) based upon the provided inputs (X) As such, I believe this is a regression problem and not a classification problem (correct me if I am wrong)

Sample data:

```
X:  [100, 200, 400, 600, 32, 1, 0.1, 0.5, 2500...]  (308 columns, with 40000+ rows)
Y:  [0.333, 0.667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
```

In the case of Y above, this means that 0.333 (33%) of the resource is allocated to first resource, 0.667 (67%) is allocated to the second resource and 0.0 to all others)

Model:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(308,) ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(256,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(28))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Here are a few specific questions:

```
1.  Is my model configured properly to achieve my goals?
2.  Should I have different activation functions?
3.  Are my input shapes (308,) setup properly? Are my output shapes (28) correct?
4.  Should I have an activation on my output layer (for example: model.add(Activation('softmax'))?  if yes, what type would be ideal?
```

(I don't think it is particularly relevant, but I am using a Tensorflow backend)

Comment: I think this is a classification problem, since your output sums up to 1.0 and reflects probabilities rather than continuous values/predictions at similar scale of the input values. Try to use 'softmax' after your last layer and loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'

Comment: I thought this was a regression problem since the targets (Y) do not reflect a particular class but rather percentages (in my case allocation pct to a resource) - a target row will have many values reflecting percentages and not one specific value identifying a classification.

Comment: Oh yes, seems reasonable. I forgot that your Y doesn't reflect only one specific class like a one-hot vector.

Comment: NNs always work better with *normalized* data; you should normalize your `X` in [0, 1] (I guess your `Y` already lies in this range)...

Comment: Also, although you are indeed in a regression context, the nature of your output `Y` is such that it may justify an experiment with a `softmax` activation in the last layer (although, according to the "rulebook", you should not try such a thing for regression)...

Comment: @desertnaut - I have now normalized the data and the results appear a bit better but not good enough to believe the model is actually learning.  However, thanks for the great suggestion - I have now normalized the data since this is a best practice

Comment: @EricBroda Have you played around with the learning rate? What about increasing the hidden units or adding layers? Do those changes have any effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(308,) ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(256,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Should solve the problem. Although it seems like a regression problem, the allocations are competing with each other which makes it like a classification and requires softmax nonlinearity and categorical_crossentropy loss.

**Update**

For early stopping you'll need a validation set and the following code:

```
earlyStopping=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=0, verbose=0, mode='auto')
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=100, nb_epoch=100, verbose=1, callbacks=[earlyStopping], validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, show_accuracy=False, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None)
```

Also you'll need to define a [new custom metric function](https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics) which instead of accuracy returns cross-entropy loss. You set the metric argument in model.compile to this new function.

Comment: Just tried this --- unfortunately, it still does not converge (it is worse, actually than original)... I think it would be incorrect to treat a regression problem as a classification problem.

Comment: Your problem is not regression because different allocations are competing. It is a classification problem for which you need both softmax and categorical cross entropy. What do you mean by the model doesn't converge? can you print both training loss and eval loss? Does the training loss go down?

Comment: You could start by removing all drop outs to see first if you can overfit the training data.

Comment: I tried removing the dropouts.  The loss does converge, but to a value that is far too high.  When I try a "predict", the prediction is quite different from the expectation (test value)

Comment: Are you using early stopping? Because if that is the case you might be stopping before converging. Try to customise Keras's early stopping behaviour. In many cases the early stopping, stops somewhere that is far away from a good local minima. Try to increase the patience of the early stopping algorithm.

Comment: With this network you should be able to get a pretty good training loss. If not, there's something wrong with the optimisation method. Either learning rate is too high (which I don't think is the case because of Adam) or you're stopping the optimisation before you should which is probably because the early stopping criteria should be customised. I would totally remove early stopping criteria to see where the training loss function would go regardless of validation metric.

Comment: Also check the metric you're using (e.g. in model.compile) because your metric shouldn't be accuracy (as your labels are not 1-hot). your metric should be the same as your loss function which is categorical_crossentropy. The metric might be used for early stopping.

Comment: I appreciate the advice -- as far I can see, the code shown uses Keras defaults (I assume a reasonable/no early shutdown, and default metrics), which I figure should provide reasonable results... thanks again, any other ideas?